# Span flex element on 2 rows in a grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm working on a grid layout and I need it to be customizable dynamically. For example starting with this 4 x 2 grid:

```css
html, body {
    background: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-container {
    background: #f2f2f2;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

.grid-cell {
    flex: 1;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0 -1px -1px 0;
    padding: 10px;
}

.panel-wes {
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-top: 3px solid #e7eaec;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #e7eaec;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-cell" x="0" y="0" style="min-width: calc(25% + 1px); max-width: calc(25% + 1px); min-height: calc(50% + 1px); max-height: calc(50% + 1px);">
    <div class="panel-wes">x="0" y="0"</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell" x="1" y="0" style="min-width: calc(25% + 1px); max-width: calc(25% + 1px); min-height: calc(50% + 1px); max-height: calc(50% + 1px);">
    <div class="panel-wes">x="1" y="0"</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell" x="2" y="0" style="min-width: calc(25% + 1px); max-width: calc(25% + 1px); min-height: calc(50% + 1px); max-height: calc(50% + 1px);">
    <div class="panel-wes">x="2" y="0"</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell" x="3" y="0" style="min-width: calc(25% + 1px); max-width: calc(25% + 1px); min-height: calc(50% + 1px); max-height: calc(50% + 1px);">
    <div class="panel-wes">x="3" y="0"</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell" x="0" y="1" style="min-width: calc(25% + 1px); max-width: calc(25% + 1px); min-height: calc(50% + 1px); max-height: calc(50% + 1px);">
    <div class="panel-wes">x="0" y="1"</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell" x="1" y="1" style="min-width: calc(25% + 1px); max-width: calc(25% + 1px);">
    <div class="panel-wes">x="1" y="1"</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell" x="2" y="1" style="min-width: calc(25% + 1px); max-width: calc(25% + 1px); min-height: calc(50% + 1px); max-height: calc(50% + 1px);">
    <div class="panel-wes">x="2" y="1"</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell" x="3" y="1" style="min-width: calc(25% + 1px); max-width: calc(25% + 1px); min-height: calc(50% + 1px); max-height: calc(50% + 1px);">
    <div class="panel-wes">x="3" y="1"</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can make one of my tiles span on multiple columns this way:

```css
html, body {
    background: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-container {
    background: #f2f2f2;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

.grid-cell {
    flex: 1;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0 -1px -1px 0;
    padding: 10px;
}

.panel-wes {
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-top: 3px solid #e7eaec;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #e7eaec;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-cell" x="0" y="0" style="min-width: calc(50% + 1px); max-width: calc(50% + 1px); min-height: calc(50% + 1px); max-height: calc(50% + 1px);">
    <div class="panel-wes">x="0" y="0"</div>
  </div>
  <!--div class="grid-cell" x="1" y="0" style="min-width: calc(25% + 1px); max-width: calc(25% + 1px); min-height: calc(50% + 1px); max-height: calc(50% + 1px);">
    <div class="panel-wes">x="1" y="0"</div>
  </div-->
  <div class="grid-cell" x="2" y="0" style="min-width: calc(25% + 1px); max-width: calc(25% + 1px); min-height: calc(50% + 1px); max-height: calc(50% + 1px);">
    <div class="panel-wes">x="2" y="0"</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell" x="3" y="0" style="min-width: calc(25% + 1px); max-width: calc(25% + 1px); min-height: calc(50% + 1px); max-height: calc(50% + 1px);">
    <div class="panel-wes">x="3" y="0"</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell" x="0" y="1" style="min-width: calc(25% + 1px); max-width: calc(25% + 1px); min-height: calc(50% + 1px); max-height: calc(50% + 1px);">
    <div class="panel-wes">x="0" y="1"</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell" x="1" y="1" style="min-width: calc(25% + 1px); max-width: calc(25% + 1px);">
    <div class="panel-wes">x="1" y="1"</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell" x="2" y="1" style="min-width: calc(25% + 1px); max-width: calc(25% + 1px); min-height: calc(50% + 1px); max-height: calc(50% + 1px);">
    <div class="panel-wes">x="2" y="1"</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell" x="3" y="1" style="min-width: calc(25% + 1px); max-width: calc(25% + 1px); min-height: calc(50% + 1px); max-height: calc(50% + 1px);">
    <div class="panel-wes">x="3" y="1"</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I can't find a way to span a tile on multiple rows because this is what happens when I try:

```css
html, body {
    background: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-container {
    background: #f2f2f2;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

.grid-cell {
    flex: 1;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0 -1px -1px 0;
    padding: 10px;
}

.panel-wes {
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-top: 3px solid #e7eaec;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #e7eaec;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-cell" x="0" y="0" style="min-width: calc(25% + 1px); max-width: calc(25% + 1px); min-height: calc(100% + 1px); max-height: calc(100% + 1px);">
    <div class="panel-wes">x="0" y="0"</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell" x="1" y="0" style="min-width: calc(25% + 1px); max-width: calc(25% + 1px); min-height: calc(50% + 1px); max-height: calc(50% + 1px);">
    <div class="panel-wes">x="1" y="0"</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell" x="2" y="0" style="min-width: calc(25% + 1px); max-width: calc(25% + 1px); min-height: calc(50% + 1px); max-height: calc(50% + 1px);">
    <div class="panel-wes">x="2" y="0"</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell" x="3" y="0" style="min-width: calc(25% + 1px); max-width: calc(25% + 1px); min-height: calc(50% + 1px); max-height: calc(50% + 1px);">
    <div class="panel-wes">x="3" y="0"</div>
  </div>
  <!--div class="grid-cell" x="0" y="1" style="min-width: calc(25% + 1px); max-width: calc(25% + 1px); min-height: calc(50% + 1px); max-height: calc(50% + 1px);">
    <div class="panel-wes">x="0" y="1"</div>
  </div-->
  <div class="grid-cell" x="1" y="1" style="min-width: calc(25% + 1px); max-width: calc(25% + 1px);">
    <div class="panel-wes">x="1" y="1"</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell" x="2" y="1" style="min-width: calc(25% + 1px); max-width: calc(25% + 1px); min-height: calc(50% + 1px); max-height: calc(50% + 1px);">
    <div class="panel-wes">x="2" y="1"</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell" x="3" y="1" style="min-width: calc(25% + 1px); max-width: calc(25% + 1px); min-height: calc(50% + 1px); max-height: calc(50% + 1px);">
    <div class="panel-wes">x="3" y="1"</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I found an article talking about this and it suggested to create a "column" div but then I will not be able to achieve horizontal spanning. Is there any known solution to this problem?

Comment: [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout). Current support: [69.31%](http://caniuse.com/css-grid/embed). Or use current [gridster](https://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/demos/responsive.html)-like plugins, all based on absolute positioning on a pre-calculated grid. According to [ask], your question is off-topic on [so], as it's too broad and also a request for (re)search more than anything else (which is a pre-requisite of asking on SO).

Comment: Not sure what your styles are doing but if I remove your styles for widths and heights and just use 50% height and 25% widths, then you can just change the direction of the flex - messes up the order of divs though: https://jsfiddle.net/s3w5x4ra/

Comment: @Pete I need to keep the order and anyway, with your method i cannot spann horizontally anymore.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I don't need old IE compatibility but letting out all the android/ios browser in 2017 is a big deal...

Comment: I never said CSS Grid is production ready. I just pointed to it as it's what you seem to want. But, if you think about it, the only way to do this is by specify-ing specific rules for every case and re-calculating sizes and positions of elements on window and element resize. Even so, you will still have cases where person A thinks a particular element should go in one slot and person B thinks it should go into another. There are no magical "make me perfect website" buttons in web design. It's all programming and handling of cases. Welcome to frontend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your current grid system, you would need to do something like this: add a second column as a sibling of the 100% height one and then put the remaining boxes inside the second column.

In the below code, I added the wrapper cell and added `display:flex` to that cell.  I then changed the widths of the cells inside that wrapper to 33%.

I have also removed the padding from the wrapper grid-cell (because of your negative margins, it actually needs 1px padding to remove the padding)

Finally, I added a horizontal span cell too, just to show you it does both

```css
html,
body {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-container {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid-cell {
  display: flex; /* add this */
  flex: 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 -1px -1px 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.panel-wes {
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-top: 3px solid #e7eaec;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #e7eaec;
}

.no-padding {
  padding: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-cell" x="0" y="0" style="min-width: calc(25% + 1px); max-width: calc(25% + 1px); min-height: calc(100% + 1px); max-height: calc(100% + 1px);">
    <div class="panel-wes">x="0" y="0"</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell no-padding">
    <div class="grid-cell" x="1" y="0" style="min-width: calc(33% + 1px); max-width: calc(33% + 1px); min-height: calc(50% + 1px); max-height: calc(50% + 1px);">
      <div class="panel-wes">x="1" y="0"</div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell" x="2" y="0" style="min-width: calc(33% + 1px); max-width: calc(33% + 1px); min-height: calc(50% + 1px); max-height: calc(50% + 1px);">
      <div class="panel-wes">x="2" y="0"</div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell" x="3" y="0" style="min-width: calc(33% + 1px); max-width: calc(33% + 1px); min-height: calc(50% + 1px); max-height: calc(50% + 1px);">
      <div class="panel-wes">x="3" y="0"</div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell" x="1" y="1" style="min-width: calc(33% + 1px); max-width: calc(33% + 1px); min-height: calc(50% + 1px); max-height: calc(50% + 1px);">
      <div class="panel-wes">x="1" y="1"</div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell" x="2" y="1" style="min-width: calc(66% + 1px); max-width: calc(33% + 1px);">
      <div class="panel-wes">x="2" y="1"</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I got this correctly, he wants to be able to dynamically extend items both vertically and horizontally, with the rest just re-positioning to best fit the remaining slots. He's basically looking for a clever masonry (probably with a  [`stamp`](https://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#stamp) method).

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, OP just wants to know how they can use their grid system to span multiple rows

Comment: Actually this answer does what i was looking for. The width/height calculations are a bit harder because for every tile i need to know how much the other ones span, i can't just say "this tile is 1/4" of screen but for the moment i can certainly use this method.

Comment: @user3825614 Just thought the no padding might need to be `padding: 0 1px 1px 0;` as you only have negative margin on 2 sides